# Error fetching data: Errno::ENETUNREACH: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. Error in installing gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems

I am new to Ruby on rails. My back end is PostgreSql. When i try to instal postgre sql with the command

```
$ gem install pg
$ gem install ruby-postgres
```

I get the following error.

```
WARNING:  Error fetching data: Errno::ENETUNREACH: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/l
atest_specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'pg' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: pg
```

I am using eclipse IDE in windows 7 platform. I have set proxy with the following command

```
$ http_proxy="http:/192.168.xx.xxx:xxxx"
```

But it still not working. My frerence where [this](https://memset.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/bash-http_proxy-from-a-user-environment-to-sudo-one/) ,[this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and [this](http://rubyonrailswin.wordpress.com/2010/03/12/getting-postgresql-to-install-on-windows/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `$ http_proxy="http:/192.168.xx.xxx:xxxx"`

Try:

```
$ http_proxy="http://192.168.xx.xxx:xxxx"
```